# In JSF how to invoke java script after getting a value using backing bean method

Tags: javascript, jsf, google-maps-api-3

I am developing a functionality in my jsf application, which should retrieve the lat and lon of places from the database and plot it in Google map. Since [gmaps4jsf](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps4jsf/) library is not updated with [google maps java script api v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/), i'm using google maps java script api as it is. The problem is that I can't call the script to plot the place in map after retrieving the lat and lon (via jsf).

What is the solution to this problem?

Comment: Welcome to StackOVerflow. We don't really care about your company name/address/etc. so there's no need to put it in your signature.

Comment: How exactly do you get the coordinates from the server? Please add some code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just let JSF print it as if it's a JS variable.

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{bean.submit}" />
</h:form>
<h:outputScript rendered="#{not empty bean.lat and not empty bean.lon}">
    var lat = #{bean.lat};
    var lon = #{bean.lon};
    initializeMapSomehowWith(lat, lon);
</h:outputScript>
```

*(the `<h:outputScript>` generates a HTML `<script type="text/javascript">` element, if you're still on old JSF 1.x, use `<h:panelGroup><script>` instead and also `<h:outputText>` instead of EL in template text)*

with something like

```
public void submit() {
    lat = 12.106173;
    lon = -68.935304;
}
```

Remember: JSF basically generates HTML. JS is part of HTML response.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Issue is that 2 actions has to be performed when the user clicks a buttonretrieving lat and lon from jsf and this value has to be used to plot the location in map using java script has to be accomplished in the user's click event.

Comment: Then just let JSF print that piece of HTML/JS conditionally with `rendered` attribute on for example some parent `<h:panelGroup>`. In the action method you of course take care that the `rendered` condition will evaluate `true` instead of default `false`.

Comment: Sorry I submitted the edit half way through by mistake.                 Thanks for your input. Requirement: 2 actions has to be performed when the user clicks a button. 1. Lat and Lon value needs to be retrieved from back end(preferably using jsf) . 2. The retrieved value then has to be used to plot the location in map using java script. I am able to do any one of the action above. Issue is, I am not able to accomplish both as mentioned in the sequence above.                                       Could you please suggest?

Comment: The script got generated, but how to invoke that?

Comment: The `initializeMapSomehowWith()` function example does that. Substitute it with whatever JS function you need to invoke with the given arguments.

Comment: Just do exactly the same as you would do with Gmap API in "plain JavaScript" to initialize the gmap.